# Cannot install Windows 8 Transformation Pack on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, themes

I am trying to install [Windows 8 Transformation Pack](http://www.windowsxlive.net/windows-8-transformation-pack) v4.0 on my [Sony Vaio laptop](http://store.sony.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666033768#additionalImage1%22) with the following options:

[image: w8tpsetupscreen1]

When I run (as administrator) the setup file, it starts to install but gives the following error at some point:

> The file 'C:\Windows\Fonts\segoui.ttf' could not be opened. Please check that your disk is not full and that you have access to the destination directory.

[image: error]

Since I run the installer as administrator, this error message seems strange to me. Segoe UI font is also installed on my PC.

When I try to install with default system fonts (without Segoe UI), it gives the same error again:

[image: w8tpsetupscreen2]
[image: error]

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: From the webiste: "For those who have installing font error during installation, please reboot and run the installation again to fix permission problem. I don't know why some cases have this and I'm investigating on it now."
Read more at http://www.windowsxlive.net/windows-8-transformationux-pack-4.0-released#9oXVqrxkhXPXj4Mm.99

Comment: I've restarted & re-run the installation many times but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling that font? (if possible)

Comment: No I haven't...

Comment: As a side note, why would you *want* to turn Windows 7 into Windows 8? Ew!

Comment: Why not? 8 is greater than 7. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the developer fixed it.

> **[Changelog](http://www.windowsxlive.net/windows-8-transformation-pack)**
>
> **Version 4.0 (Proper)**
>
> -Fixed Segoe fonts family installation that fails to update in some Vista/7 platforms

Answer (score 0):

The SegoeUI font has been significantly changed in 8, so if SegoeUI in 7 is being over-written (updated) during this 8-like transformation, that may have caused some permission issues. I wonder if the 'transformation pack' actually 'updates' the 7 SegoeUI, or did they just avoid the issue with a workaround that leaves SegoeUI unchanged? The improvements to this important Windows font should be a welcome improvement in 7, especially visually, assuming there are no other conflicts.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).